# Erro ao converter projeto java com Jersey para maven

Tags: java, maven, jersey

Criei um projeto com angular e WS REST utilizando Jersey. Ele estava funcionando normal, até que fui converter o projeto pro Maven. Ao tentar subir o projeto, estou tendo os seguintes erros:

> Missing dependency for constructor public
>   org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.DocumentProvider(org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyConfiguration)
>   at parameter index 0   Missing dependency for constructor public
>   org.jboss.resteasy.core.AsynchronousDispatcher(org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyProviderFactory)
>   at parameter index 0

Alguém pode me ajudar a resolver?

POM.xml

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
    http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>WebService</groupId>
  <artifactId>WebService</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
      <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.annotation</groupId>
      <artifactId>jboss-annotations-api_1.2_spec</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.ejb</groupId>
      <artifactId>jboss-ejb-api_3.2_spec</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.el</groupId>
      <artifactId>jboss-el-api_3.0_spec</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.7.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
      <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.faces</groupId>
      <artifactId>jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
      <version>1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.interceptor</groupId>
      <artifactId>jboss-interceptors-api_1.2_spec</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.jms</groupId>
      <artifactId>jboss-jms-api_2.0_spec</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
      <version>1.5.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.management.j2ee</groupId>
      <artifactId>jboss-j2eemgmt-api_1.1_spec</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.resource</groupId>
      <artifactId>jboss-connector-api_1.7_spec</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.security.auth.message</groupId>
      <artifactId>jboss-jaspi-api_1.1_spec</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.security.jacc</groupId>
      <artifactId>jboss-jacc-api_1.5_spec</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
      <artifactId>jboss-jsp-api_2.3_spec</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.servlet.jstl</groupId>
      <artifactId>jboss-jstl-api_1.2_spec</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.3.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction</groupId>
      <artifactId>jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
      <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.ws.rs</groupId>
      <artifactId>jboss-jaxrs-api_2.0_spec</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>wsdl4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>wsdl4j</artifactId>
      <version>1.6.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.xml.bind</groupId>
      <artifactId>jboss-jaxb-api_2.2_spec</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.4.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.xml.rpc</groupId>
      <artifactId>jboss-jaxrpc-api_1.1_spec</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.xml.soap</groupId>
      <artifactId>jboss-saaj-api_1.3_spec</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.3.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.xml.ws</groupId>
      <artifactId>jboss-jaxws-api_2.2_spec</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.3.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
      <version>5.2.4.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.picketbox</groupId>
      <artifactId>picketbox</artifactId>
      <version>4.9.6.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.picketbox</groupId>
      <artifactId>picketbox-commons</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0.final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.wildfly.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>wildfly-controller-client</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss</groupId>
      <artifactId>jboss-dmr</artifactId>
      <version>1.3.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
      <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
      <version>3.3.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
      <artifactId>resteasy-jaxb-provider</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.19.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
      <artifactId>async-http-servlet-3.0</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.19.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
      <artifactId>resteasy-client</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.19.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
      <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.19.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
      <artifactId>resteasy-multipart-provider</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.19.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.ejb3</groupId>
      <artifactId>jboss-ejb3-ext-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.batch</groupId>
      <artifactId>jboss-batch-api_1.0_spec</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.enterprise.concurrent</groupId>
      <artifactId>jboss-concurrency-api_1.0_spec</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.websocket</groupId>
      <artifactId>jboss-websocket-api_1.1_spec</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>asm</groupId>
      <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
      <version>3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
      <version>1.9.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs</artifactId>
      <version>1.9.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
      <version>1.9.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-xc</artifactId>
      <version>1.9.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
      <version>1.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
      <version>1.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
      <version>1.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
      <version>1.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-multipart</artifactId>
        <version>1.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
      <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <finalName>webservice</finalName>                   
    </configuration>
</plugin>    
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
    version="3.1">
    <display-name>TesteWS</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey RESTful</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</param-name>
            <param-value>jotaws.resource</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey RESTful</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Você converteu o projeto para Maven como? Usou aquela opção do Eclipse para isso? Vai usar Jersey com RestEasy ou só Jersey?